# Does anyone know of a ServiceStack.Text branch that can Serialize private members?

Tags: c#, serialization, servicestack-text

I have a set of classes that act like Enumerators where there are two tiers to represent classifications.
Where the Key and Numeral are never exposed publicly so as to force any implementation to work with the class object itself with operators and not the properties Key and Numeral. I am using ServiceStack to serialize classes that have this EnumClass nested in them. Of course ServiceStack.Text, as is, doesn't support private members to be serialized but I was wondering if someone has developed a branch of it that does?

Example code to top or parent tier:

```
[Serializable]
public class EnumClass
{
    [DataMember]
    protected internal String Key;
    [DataMember]
    protected internal Byte Numeral;

    public EnumClass(String _key, Byte _number)
    {
        Key = _key;
        Numeral = _number;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(EnumClass anEnum)
    {
        return anEnum.Numeral;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(EnumClass anEnum)
    {
        return anEnum.Key;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(EnumClass))
            result = Equals((EnumClass)obj);
        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(int))
            result = Equals((int)obj);
        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(String))
            result = Equals(obj.ToString());
        return result;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return Key;
    }        

    public bool Equals(EnumClass anEnum)
    {
        return anEnum.Equals((int)Numeral);
    }

    public bool Equals(int value)
    {
        return Numeral == (byte)value;
    }

    public bool Equals(string value)
    {
        return Key == value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //return Key.GetHashCode() ^ Numeral.GetHashCode();
        int result = 0;
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            result = (int)2166136261;
            result = ShiftBits.ShiftAndWrap((result * 16777619) ^ Numeral, 2);
            for (int x = 0; x < Key.Length; x++)
            {
                result = ShiftBits.ShiftAndWrap((result * 16777619) ^ Key[x], 2);
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely bad idea. Wrapping enum why? Can you explain thi bit more?

Comment: I'm not wrapping enum but creating an on the fly enumerator whose modification can be persisted by saving it to a file or DB. So rather than use reflection to modify an enum which is very slow and would not persist, this approach is used.